# print (big) list with format with for loop

Tags: python, format

I have an array on hand. Now I'd like to have a combined print of text and array entries, so I'd use .format.

I'd like to now if there is a way to get the following work with that for loop (not a[0],a[1],a[2]).

```
a = [1,2,3]
print("""
A is {}
B is {}
C is {}
""".format(i for i in a))
```

This one returns `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `*` to unpack the arguments as an argument list:

```
a = [1,2,3]
print("""
A is {}
B is {}
C is {}
""".format(*[i for i in a]))
```

Or even better, if you’re not dependent on the individual contents of the list;

```
a = [1,2,3]
print("""
A is {}
B is {}
C is {}
""".format(*a))
```

Python reads both of these identically: `*a` is unpacked as an argument list. You can do something similar with dictionaries (using a double `**` which unpacks keyword arguments):

```
a = {"alpha": 1, "beta": 2, "gamma":3}
print("""
A is {alpha}
B is {beta}
C is {gamma}
""".format(**a))
```